# Display the first word of input string in UpperCase letters in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

How to display the first word of input string in uppercase letters. Display with using message   box.

Example:

```
inputed String = Advance Programing using VB.Net
```

the function should display = ADVANCE

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim words = input.Split() 
Dim result = String.Format("{0} {1}",
                           words(0).ToUpper(),
                           String.Join(" ", words.Skip(1)))
```

Edit: oh, just the first word, then use `words(0).ToUpper`

Comment: No validation on empty strings/string with no spaces?

Comment: a null string would raise an exception. But you're right, it's out of scope of the question.

Comment: @MarcelDevG: i don't know the context of this code at all. So _maybe_ it is a method, then it might be incorrect to process a null-string in which case a `ArgumentNullException` would be appropriate. However, i simply I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function GetFirstWordUpperCase(ByVal input As String) As String
    Return If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input), Nothing, input.Split()(0).ToUpper())
End Function
```

Checks if the input string is null, empty or whitespace then returns what you wanted if it is not.

For instance, `GetFirstWordUpperCase("how are you")` returns "HOW"

Simply do `MsgBox(GetFirstWordUpperCase("how are you"))` to display the result.

Btw instead of returning Nothing, you could throw an error and catch it where you use the function, it's just the basic idea.